# UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

On one of my machines I have the error when I am working with google apps engine or django.

For example:

- app.yaml

  ```
  application: demas1252c
  version: 1
  runtime: python
  api_version: 1


  handlers:
     - url: /images
  static_dir: images
     - url: /css
  static_dir: css
     - url: /js
  static_dir: js
     - url: /.*
  script: demas1252c.py
  ```
- demas1252c.py

  ```
  import cgi
  import wsgiref.handlers


  from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
  from google.appengine.ext import webapp


  class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler): 
  def get(self):
  values = {'id' : 10}


  self.response.out.write(template.render('foto.html', values))


  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug = True)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
  ```
- foto.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head></head>
  <body>some</body>
  </html>
  ```

error message:

```
C:\artefacts\dev\project>"c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" foto-hosting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 69, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 65, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 92, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 140, in <module>
    mimetypes.add_type(mime_type, '.' + ext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 344, in add_type
    init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 260, in read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 250, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I am working with static files in django (without gae) I have very similar error (with different stack).

I tried to find the reason of error and added code to mimetypes.py:

```
print '====='
print ctype
ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
```

Then I get next messages in my console:

```
=====
video/x-ms-wvx
=====
video/x-msvideo
=====
рєфшю/AMR
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

In the registry HKCR/Mime/Database/ContentType/ I have five keys with russian (cyrilic) letters.  But how can I fix this error?

Comment: What is the value of "default_encoding", right now it seems that it's something that cannot convert cyrilic, using UTF-8 here should probably fix the error.

Comment: ascii. i tryed to change it to utf-8, but I get error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: invalid continuation byte". Anyway, I remove this keys from registry and error dissapeared.

Comment: this is a bug mimetype.py changed the python code at this url
http://bugs.python.org/review/9291/diff/1663/Lib/mimetypes.py

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is a bug in `mimetypes`, triggered by bad data in the registry. (`рєфшю/AMR` is not at all a valid MIME media type.)

`ctype` is a registry key name returned by `_winreg.EnumKey`, which `mimetypes` is expecting to be a Unicode string, but it isn't. Unlike `_winreg.QueryValueEx`, `EnumKey` returns a byte string (direct from the ANSI version of the Windows API; `_winreg` in Python 2 doesn't use the Unicode interfaces even though it returns Unicode strings, so it'll never read non-ANSI characters correctly).

So the attempt to `.encode` it fails with a Unicode​**Decode**​Error trying to get a Unicode string before encoding it back to ASCII!

```
try:
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    pass
```

These lines in `mimetypes` should simply be removed.

ETA: [added to bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue10490).

Comment: Thank's, this fixed my problem with IPython on Anaconda v2.1!

Answer (score 8):

By the way, the main culpit of the problem is QuickTime which adds non-ascii mime types to the windows registry. The easiest way to fix it is to manually find and remove from the registry the subsections of the `HKCR/Mime/Database/ContentType/` starting with `аудио/` and `видео/`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a patch:

http://bugs.python.org/file18143/9291.patch

Works great for me.

Just replace UnicodeEncodeError to be UnicodeError

Comment: The accepted answer worked, I did not try this one, but I think it will work, too.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution from [python issue9291 by Alexandr Zarubkin (me21)](http://bugs.python.org/issue9291#msg206938):

add file named sitecustomize.py in Lib\site-packages folder.

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1251")
```

Answer (score 1):

its a python bug with latin MIME tipes in registry
start regedit and inspect "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type" for non-latin names.