# UnicodeDecodeError in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I get the following error code when trying to load the template.

'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 720: invalid start byte

Here is the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block site_wrapper %}
<div id="main">
<a href="#content" class="skip_link">Skip to main content</a>
<div id="banner">
    <div class="bannerIEPadder">
        <div class="cart_box">
            [link to cart here]
        </div>
        Modern Musician
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="navIEPadder">
        [navigation here]
    </div>
</div>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebarIEPadder">
            [search box here]
            <br/>
            [category listing here]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <a name=”content”></a>
        <div class="contentIEPadder">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footerIEPadder">
        [footer here]
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Post a stack trace, pls.

Comment: Looks like my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237898/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe0-in-position-0-ordinal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some strange characters in my code because i copied out of a pdf-file.

Answer (score 3):

In UTF-8 0x94 is nothing, however in ISO1252 it's a right quote (”). Generally speaking the plain quote (") is much safer.

Make sure you're not copying and pasting this out of some blog that has weird accented quotes or something like that.

If you're using a text editor save it as ascii and see what crops up missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have weird double quotes around div#content, try replacing them with ASCII quotes.

Maybe your template is encoded with something other than utf-8? It depends on your terminal/editor or maybe OS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error . . . and it turned out that the problem was I included a "©" in my source copied as a part of a template.
Got to check that code for strange characters.........