# Anaconda ipython-notebook getting "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed `Anaconda-1.9.1-Windows-x86.exe` and tried to start ipython-notebook after installation. However I got such an error:

```
2014-03-15 17:00:48.724 [tornado.application] ERROR | Uncaught exception GET /st
atic/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1)
HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/static/c
omponents/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css', version='HTTP/1.1', re
mote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encod
ing': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'Accept': 'text/css,*/*;q=0
.1', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTM
L, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0', 'Accept-Cha
rset': 'GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'http:/
/127.0.0.1:8888/'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1218, in _when_compl
ete
    callback()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1239, in _execute_me
thod
    self._when_complete(method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs),
......
......
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1: ordinal
not in range(128)
2014-03-15 17:00:50.220 [tornado.access] ERROR | 500 GET /static/tree/js/noteboo
klist.js (127.0.0.1) 98.00ms
```

[Full traceback is here](http://codepad.org/Xz7SN8MT), I'm not sure what's happening.

I'm on win7 x64, and my last installation of `anaconda 1.5.0` worked perfect. I'm guessing `anaconda 1.9.1` may has some bugs dealing with unicode. Hope someone experienced could help ;). I'll have to downgrade now ;\

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in mimetypes.py.  Some program inserted a Unicode entry into the system registry and mimetypes is trying to decode it as ascii.

There is a patch, mentioned in this answer: [UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237898/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe0-in-position-0-ordinal)

Here is a link to the actual patch itself: http://bugs.python.org/file18143/9291.patch

Assuming that your anaconda install is in the default place: C:\Anaconda, you can fix this issue quickly by opening a text editor and modifying C:\Anaconda\Lib\mimetypes.py by adding the following code on line 250:

```
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Knelson probably meant adding the following code on line 250 (which solved the problem for me):

```
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    pass
```

Not the `UnicodeEncodeError`

Comment: Isn't it just hiding the exception?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the folder path contains a Chinese part which makes the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by changing files:

- \Anaconda2\Lib\ntpath.py:

`result_path = result_path + p_path` to

```
try:
    result_path = result_path + p_path
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass
```

- \Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py

`homedir = os.path.realpath(homedir)` to

`homedir = os.path.realpath(homedir).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`

and `appdata = os.environ.get('APPDATA', None)` to

`appdata = os.environ.get('APPDATA', None).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`

- \Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py

`home = os.path.expanduser('~')` to

`home = os.path.expanduser('~').decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`