# What causes this error from pip or easy_install on Windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, anaconda

I setuped Anaconda and setuptools from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). Presently If I try to install any module from command line on Windows, I enocunter this error message.

```
C:\Users\XXX>pip install theano
Downloading/unpacking theano
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122,
in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line
278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl
e=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prep
are_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 292, in run_e
gg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.s
etup_py, self.name))
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 265, in setup
_py
    import setuptools
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 1
2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line
7, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, i
n <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 6,
 in <module>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19,
 in <module>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 214, in SimpleHTTP
RequestHandler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 348, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Users\eren\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 256, in read_windows_regi
stry
    with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\eren\pip\pip.log
```

Do you have any idea about his error?

I reinstalled all the setuptools again withdifferent versions but the error is still persistent. The interesesting fact is I can remove any module installed with Anaconda but installation raises error.

Comment: Something in your registry is wrong. The error is coming from Python itself, not setuptools. It is looking for some keys in your registry and it can't find them.

Comment: any idea for "How to solve"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25490132/161801 seems related. You may also try looking in the registry for bad values.