# AppEngine - error uploading data to local server

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

I am following AppEngine tutorial on [this website](https://cloud.google.com/resources/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial)
When I try to upload data to local server using this script(**upload_data.bat**):

```
#!/bin/sh
C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --filename $1 --kind=$2 -e nobody@nowhere.com
```

I get error:

```
$ upload_data.bat places.csv Place
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 127, in
<module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 123, in
run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 177, in <module>
    augment_mimetypes.init()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\au
gment_mimetypes.py", line 23, in init
    mimetypes.add_type('application/dart', '.dart')
  File "c:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 347, in add_type
    init()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 13: ordinal
 not in range(128)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show your `bulkloader.yaml` file?

Comment: [bulkloader.yaml](http://pastebin.com/wzH42B83)

Comment: Can you give it a try with `encoding: utf-8` added into `connector_options:` section and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://pastebin.com/Qqpmr1dU)? It did not help

Comment: Don't know if it matters much but [try adding an extra tab before "encoding: utf-8"](http://pastebin.com/QgCgMsT3) (all of them actually, in the pastbin link I only did it for the first one).

Comment: It also didn`t help(

Comment: I resolved my problem using [this recomendation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4238212/3582827)